# CouchDb End Users

Tags: couchdb

So, I'm trying to get started with CouchDB (and NoSQL in general), coming from a well-entrenched background in T-SQL, and I'm running into a bit of a mental roadblock. I'm unsure how to model an end user in my CouchDB database.

My main point of confusion, is that it seems to me that the default _users document in CouchDB is supposed to handle all types of user. In effect, this document should contain user information for both my SA user, as well as some guy on the internet who registered today. Is this the case, or am I horribly misreading the entire thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the documentation regarding [security](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/security.html). The `_users` database contains "registered users" as you have discovered. However, "system users" (admins) are configured seperately and exist in the `config.ini` rather than in the database itself.

Comment: Thanks for that page! That clears things up greatly. I was on an entirely different guide (might not have been from CouchDb directly now that i think about it), that really confused matters.